# C++17 parallel algorithms on containers with object data

Tags: stl, c++17

I am attempting to use C++17 parallel algorithms with containers holding non-fundamental types as illustrated in the minimal example below, compiled using GCC9.2.1/Intel TBB on Ubuntu 19.10. The sequential policy is OK, but compilation fails with `par` since the lambda is expected to accept `double` as the second argument. The issue persists on icc 19.0.1.
My question is if the code is valid or if this issue is simply because of the early development stage of the parallel implementation?

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>

struct Data {
    double radius;
};

int main() {
    double sum;
    std::vector<double> v1;
    std::vector<Data> v2;

    // ok
    sum = std::reduce(std::execution::par, v1.begin(), v1.end(), 0.0, [](double sum, auto i) { return sum + i; });

    // ok
    sum = std::reduce(std::execution::seq, v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0.0, [](double sum, const Data &i) { return sum + i.radius; });

    // compile error
    sum = std::reduce(std::execution::par, v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0.0, [](double sum, const Data &i) { return sum + i.radius; });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*BinaryOp* for `std::reduce` should be commutative, below both operations should be supported:

```
double + Data // your lambda supports only this 
Data + double // this can be performed only by adding some conversions
```

If you want to make conversion `double->Data` you should add proper constructor. For conversion `Data->double` you should add proper conversion operator:

```
struct Data {
    double radius;

    // double -> Data
    Data (double d) : radius(d) {}

    // Data -> double
    operator double() const {
        return radius;
    }
};
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E8jmde)

Comment: Thanks, so the example using `seq` policy is also invalid, although the compiler doesn't complain? The struct is merely a simple example and in my application I would send in a range containing tuples of objects like so:

~~~ cpp
std::reduce(std::execution::seq, pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), 0.0,
    [&](double sum, const auto &pair) {
    return sum + func(std::get<0>(pair), std::get<1>(pair));
    })
~~~

Again this compiles with `seq`; do you see a solution to solve this?

Comment: IMO it is also invalid. As per [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce), type requirements -  *and binary_op(init, *first), binary_op(*first, init), binary_op(init, init), and binary_op(*first, *first) must be convertible to T.*. `pair<double,double>` is not convertible to `double`.

Comment: I ended up creating a range (range-v3) like so `auto v3 = v2 | ranges::cpp20::views::transform([](const auto &i){return i.radius;});` and `std::reduce(v3.begin(), v3.end(), 0.0);` which gave close to linear scaling on my setup.